# How to hover on page load and minor hover style issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to repliace google's homepage as part of an html and css course I started. I can't figure out how to add a shadow on the search box when the page loads, just like with Google's website.

Also, when hovering the top-right image, it changes the transparency but this should not be happening. How can I take remove that effect?

Page is here:
https://odiseon.github.io/google-homepage/

Answer (score 0):

Looked at your code, this what causes issue on hover

```
header a:hover {
    opacity: 0.85;
}
```

You can do something like this

```
header a.user-link:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Looking at the google page behavior, it starts off with the class that has box-shadow and then after first mouse click it's removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript.

`window.onload`

and then add the classname to your input field.

use the below code as a reference.

***index.html***

```
<input type='text' class='input'>
```

***app.js***

```
window.onload = (event) => {
  document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('.input:focus{ 
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 0 (0,0,0,0.2); 
  }', 0);
}
```

Comment: I pushed your suggestions so they can be reviewed, but it does not seem to work :(